# How to run C codes in matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I want to run a c++ code in Matlab, in my code I have this

```
    int max=(int)*mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    double a[max];
```

but when I use mex it has these errors

error C2057: expected constant expression
error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
'a' : unknown size

all for line 2, and I get errors for this file only , (I can mex example codes)
any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: C++ doesn't support variable sized arrays. You may want to use `std::vector<double> a(max);`, or `double *a = mxCalloc(max, sizeof(double));`. Hard to recommend a solution without knowing what you intend to do with the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `max` is not a constant expression (or, at least, not marked as being constant). For the second line to work, you must have `max` being a constant, because the memory footprint of the array must be known prior execution (the array is allocated on the stack). If you do not know the size, you need to use something like

```
double *a = mxCalloc(max, sizeof(double));
```

Then you allocate a chunk of memory on the heap, which allows to use dynamic sizes.